# Rename files by comparing the filenames with the names in a text file

Tags: powershell

I have some files as

```
young Devils.mkv
hellraiser.avi
Hellraiser 2.mkv
```

I have in same folder a text file called `movielist.txt` that contains this text

```
Ghost (1990)
Young Devils (1999)
Hellraiser (1987)
Hellraiser 2 (1988)
They Live (1988)
```

I try to rename my files in this way

```
Young Devils (1999).mkv
Hellraiser (1987).avi
Hellraiser 2 (1988).mkv
```

One idea is this, but I don't understand how the comparison with the names in the text file should happen

```
$rootFolder = 'C:\Test'
$FilesToChange = 'FileNames'
$FileNames = Get-Content "$BasePath\movielist.txt"
# get a list of files
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Directory | Sort-Object {$_.Name.Length} -Descending
# find files that match their names
foreach ($FileNames in $files) {
    # use the filenames in movielist.txt as filter, surrounded with wildcard characters (*)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Filter "*$($FileNames.Name)*" -File |
```

Comment: You're missing some code, but you're also using incorrect assignments to your loop. A `foreach` statement is a construct of: (<item to represent current iteration of the RHS array> in <the array>). You assign your text names to `$FileNames` then reassign `$FileNames` to represent the current iteration of `$files`. Are there a lot of names in your text file?

Comment: do you REALLY want the following? >>> `Hellraises.avi (1987).avi` <<< that double `.avi` is kind freaky. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey sorry, I wrong to write, `Hellraiser` not `Hellraises`.. I corrected now

Comment: @AbrahamZinala in theory, yes, there will be a hundred names at least. For simplicity I have reduced it to 4 names

Comment: Does the textfile really contain `Hellraiser.avi (1987)` or should that be `Hellraiser (1987)` ? (so without `.avi`)

Comment: @Theo nono, `.avi` is just extension. I corrected names in question

Comment: @JackRock - thank you for the correction. that makes things a tad easier to understand. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would really need is to loop through your names in your .txt file, and match them with the names of the files you're looking to rename.

```
$rootFolder = "C:\Users\Abraham\Desktop\Test"
$files      = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -File | Sort-Object { $_.Name.Length } -Descending
$filesNames = Get-Content -Path "$rootFolder\TextFile2.txt"

:loop foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    foreach ($name in $filesNames)
    {
        if ($name -match [regex]::Escape($file.BaseName))
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                FileObject = $file.BaseName
                FileName   = $name
            }
            Rename-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -NewName "$name$ext" -EA 0 -WhatIf
            continue loop
        }
    } 
}
```

We do this here using the `-match` operator seeing as you can match the *BaseName* property, to the file name in your .txt file.

---

*Remove the `-WhatIf` switch when you've determined those are the results you are after.*

Comment: mm.. it removes extensions `.avi`, `.mkv` from filenames. Sorry, I omitted this detail, I wrote the extensions to make it clear that they are file names and not simple text.

Comment: @JackRock....see edit.

Comment: Ok, I test your solution but there are some problems. For example I test with 90 files (I just create empty files with extensions) that have these names: https://pastebin.com/raw/dxiKSkGW Ok, inside my *movielist.txt* I have these names https://pastebin.com/raw/9pw4MCQ3 - Many filenames are not renamed, for example `Giardini Di Pietra.avi` is not renamed into `Giardini di pietra (1987)`. On Powershell I see errors like **Operation Stopped, invalid pattern**, look this picture please https://i.imgur.com/L9zTJn8.png

Comment: @JackRock, see last edit. That's because it's using metacharacters (`[..]` and `(...)`) in the name, so they need to be escaped. We do this by using: `[Regex]::Escape($_.BaseName)`.

Comment: mm.. for example `Gli ammutinati del Bounty - Mutiny on the Bounty.avi` and `Giustizia Privata [1080p - Ita Eng].mkv` are not renamed into `Gli ammutinati del Bounty (1962)` and `Giustizia privata (2010)`

Comment: hmmm, try it with `-LiterPath` instead: `Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "$name$ext"`

Comment: I try but nothing happens

Comment: Then switch it from `$name -match [Regex]::Escape($_.BaseName)`, to `$name -like "*$($_.BaseName)*"`. Other than that, I am not reproducing the same errors. I created a text file with those names, along with those file types and don't get an error. Updated the code to what it should be

Comment: Still is not renamed `Giustizia Privata..` and `Gli ammutinati del Bounty..` I can show you, please take a look here https://i.imgur.com/9mAF9Mq.gif

Comment: I see the issue... unfortunately that's just one of many others that won't be renamed. There is just too much ambiguity going on here. Some files have the exact same name but different extension: `Giovani aquile (Flyboys) (2006).rar` and `Giovani aquile (Flyboys) (2006).avi`, just a different extension. You can use regex to match everything before the `(` for most of the names, but now you will have some that are the same name again, but the date inside `(..)` is different. This is not including the extension issue.

Comment: I highly suggest putting this info in your post next time since it will just lead to asking for more in the comments. It can be done, just very meticulous scripting will be required. If noone can get it right here for just not wanting to take the time to do it, you can always request for it to be done on fiverr.com where you can pay someone to write it for you. Sorry man, I just am not able to do it.

Comment: I ask new question here if you want to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901305/remove-matching-issues-when-files-are-compared-to-a-text-list