# Remove matching issues when files are compared to a text list

Tags: powershell

I have some files like this

```
Hooligans (BDrip (1080).mkv
Hocus Pocus [DIVX - ITA] - Walt Disney - HQ-.avi
Ho Cercato Il Tuo Nome h265.avi
Ho Cercato Il Tuo Nome 720.rar
Halloween 2 - Il Signore Della Morte.avi
Highlander 2 1080p.mkv
Heartbreakers - Vizio di famiglia.avi
Il cavaliere oscuro.mkv
Il cavaliere oscuro - il ritorno 1080p.mkv
```

In the same directory I have a text file (`movielist.txt`) that is formatted always in this way: **name + year**.
Year is always from `19**-20**` and is inside brackets

```
Hooligans (1995)
Hocus Pocus (1993)
Ho cercato il tuo nome (2012)
Halloween 2 – Il signore della morte (1981)
Highlander 2 – Il ritorno (1990)
Heartbreakers – Vizio di famiglia (2001)
Il cavaliere oscuro (2008)
Il cavaliere oscuro - Il ritorno (2012)
... other text
```

I try to rename files so:

```
Hooligans (1995).mkv
Hocus Pocus (1993).avi
Ho cercato il tuo nome (2012).avi
Ho cercato il tuo nome (2012).rar
Halloween 2 – Il signore della morte (1981).avi
Highlander 2 – Il ritorno (1990).mkv
Heartbreakers – Vizio di famiglia (2001).avi
Il cavaliere oscuro (2008).mkv
Il cavaliere oscuro - il ritorno (2012).mkv
```

**Note**: the number of files to be renamed is not the same as the number of lines in the text file. In the text file there can be 100 lines while the number of files to rename could be 50.

There are two ways to do but are insufficient to perform that I request

**1st**

```
$movieList = Get-Content movielist.txt

# enumerate all movies
:outer foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\test skript\test2" -File) {
    $bn = $file.BaseName
    # enumerate all lines of the movies to rename file
    foreach($movie in $movieList) {
        # if the Base Name is contained in the movie to rename, ie:
        # 'Young Devils (1999)' -like '*young Devils*'
        if($movie -like "*$bn*") {
            # rename the file using the movie + the file's extension, ie:
            # Young Devils (1999) + .mkv
            Rename-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -NewName ($movie + $file.Extension)
            # no need to keep comparing this file, if we're here
            # we can continue with next file
            continue outer
        }
    }
}
```

**2nd:**

```
$rootFolder = "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\test skript\test1"
$files      = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -File
$filesNames = Get-Content -Path "$rootFolder\movielist.txt"

foreach ($name in $filesNames) 
{
    $files | Where-Object -FilterScript {
        $name -match [Regex]::Escape($_.BaseName)
    } | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $ext = $_.Extension
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "$name$ext" -EA 0
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to rename the files of my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty of using your long lists of files and 'movielist.txt' from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71894413/9898643), because in there it shows there are lots of extra characters in the names that complicate things..
Not only the `(year)` in the desired names, but also some files have dots instead of spaces in their names, non-ascii hyphens (en-dashes) etc.

To do what you want you will need to

- create a title Hashtable to store the actual value from the movielist.tst file as value, but also have a cleaned-up version of that to do the comparison with
- extend each FileInfo object in the files array with an extra property (I call 'SearchName') that stores a cleaned-up version of the actual file's BaseName to compare against.

```
$titles = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\movielist.txt' -Encoding UTF8 | Select-Object -Unique
# first create a Hashtable with searchable (cleaned-up) titles and the actual title you want as filename
$titleMap = @{}
foreach ($title in $titles) {
    # remove everything after a square bracket, remove the year in between brackets, 
    # remove all non-ascii characters and trim trailing spaces
    $search = ($title -replace '(\(\d{4}\)|\[.*|\s*)$' -replace '[^\x00-\x7F]+' -replace '\.|\s+', ' ').Trim()
    $titleMap[$search] = $title
}

# next, get an array of these search titels, sorted on Length reversed
# to avoid bad renames on ambiguous names like 'Il cavaliere oscuro' and 'Il cavaliere oscuro - Il ritorno'
$searchTitles = $titleMap.Keys | Sort-Object Length -Descending


# get the list of files in the foler
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\Test' -File -Exclude 'movielist.txt'
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $search = ($file.BaseName -replace '(\(\d{4}\)|\[.*|\s*)$' -replace '[^\x00-\x7F]+' -replace '\.|\s+', ' ').Trim()
    # extend each object with a cleaned-up searchable name
    $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'SearchName' -Value $search
}

# now loop through the search titles and try to find matching filenames from the files
foreach ($title in $searchTitles) {
    $files | Where-Object { $_.SearchName -like "*$title*" } | ForEach-Object {
        # use '-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue' to avoid errors on files that have already been renamed
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}{1}' -f $titleMap[$title], $_.Extension) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

---

- Title from movietext.txt says `Highlander 2 – Il ritorno (1990)`, but filename is just `Highlander 2 1080p.mkv`. To have a match, you also need `Highlander 2` in your movietext file.
- Title from movietext.txt says `Halloween 2 – Il signore della morte (1981)`, but filename is `Halloween 2 - Il Signore Della Morte.avi`. Here again, in the text file you use an `En-Dash` instead of a normal hyphen.
- Title from movietext.txt says `Heartbreakers – Vizio di famiglia (2001)` which has an En-dash instead of the normal hyphen the filename `Heartbreakers - Vizio di famiglia.avi`, has, so they don't match.

---

Maybe, because you seem to create the movietext.txt in a word editor like Word that automatically uses typographic glyphs instead of straight characters, a better solution would be to use a helper function on top of the script:

```
function Get-ComparableName ([string]$Name) {
    $Name -replace '(\(\d{4}\)|\[.*|\s*)$' -replace                          # remove anything after (and including) a square open bracket and the year in brackets
                   '\.|\s+', ' ' -creplace                                   # replace dots into spaces and normalize spaces
                   '[\u201C\u201D\u201E\u201F\u2033\u2036]', '"' -creplace   # replace double-quote glyphs into straight quotes
                   "[\u2018\u2019\u201A\u201B\u2032\u2035]", "'" -replace    # replace single-quote glyphs into straight quotes
                   '[\p{Pd}\u2212]','-'  -replace                            # replace dash-like glyphs into a straight hyphen
                   '([^\x00-\x7F]|\p{Cf})+'                                  # remove non-ascii and invisible control characters
}
```

and use it like:

```
foreach ($title in $titles) {
    $search = (Get-ComparableName $title).Trim()
    $titleMap[$search] = $title
}
```

and a bit further down:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $search = (Get-ComparableName $file.BaseName).Trim()
    # extend each object with a cleaned-up searchable name
    $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'SearchName' -Value $search
}
```

As for the file `Highlander 2 1080p.mkv`, you need to add a title `Highlander 2 (1990)` in your movielist.txt file, otherwise it will not be matched..

Comment: There are some files that are not renamed, for example: `Halloween 2 - Il Signore Della Morte.avi`, `Highlander 2 1080p.mkv` and `Heartbreakers - Vizio di famiglia.avi`. What is the problem?

Comment: There another issue with your script. For example I have `Identita.avi` and `identita violate.rar` and inside *movielist.txt* I have `Identità violate (2004)` and `Identità (2003)`. Problem is that both filenames are named into `Identità (2003)` but this is an error because they are 2 different movies (there are 2 different years for same word "identità" in filename, in my example `identità.avi`  should be renamed into `identità (2003).avi` while compound word `identita violate.rar` should be renamed into `Identità violate (2004).rar`

Comment: @JackRock You need to make sure you have accent characters correct in both the movielist.txt file and the actual file names. If the code should also remove diacritics, that can be done, but I wonder.. What else should it take care of? What did you use to create the text file and why doesn't it match accented characters?

Comment: @JackRock Also, it is a bad idea to want to name files with typographic glyphs like the en-dash you have put in and the curly apostrophes. These are the reason for the `-replace '[^\x00-\x7F]+'`. Undoubtedly you will get yourself in trouble by doing that..

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't realize they were accented characters. I have edited movielist and now it works. But why, instead, `Halloween 2 - Il Signore Della Morte.avi`, `Highlander 2 1080p.mkv` and `Heartbreakers - Vizio di famiglia.avi` still aren't they renamed ? I checked and the movielist names are written correctly - you can see names into my question

Comment: I tried to use a text file that contained only those two names with no others, yet according to your script there should be no reason for the rename to fail. When you succeed, try to use a *movielist.txt* with just those 2 names with no others.

Comment: Ok, I understand about normal hyphen but I think that problem here is this: if you have  *Highlander.avi* and *Highlander 2 1080p.mkv* like filenames and into movielist.txt you have `Highlander (1986)` and `Highlander 2 - Il ritorno (1990)`, then your script do 2 things: **1.** it doesn't rename *highlander.avi* into `Highlander (1986)` not only that, but **2.** also rename *Highlander 2 1080p.mkv* into `Highlander (1986)` but this is an error because exchange name of one movie for another ! Perhaps it is better that I write another post because  you risk having films, but with wrong names.

Comment: @JackRock I have added an alternative using a helper function. But, as said, you need to insert an item `Highlander 2 (1990)` in your movielist.txt file. Now you have only `Highlander 2 - Il ritorno (1990)` which will not match `Highlander 2 1080p.mkv` (because this file does not also have `- Il ritorno`...

Comment: Thank you very much Theo for helper function and all tips. Yes, after adding `Highlander 2 (1990)` in text file it renames correctly. I will therefore have to pay attention and see the presence of this type of filenames so that I can add them as you indicated

Answer (score 1):

No fancy regex here other than making an array of movie names and years

```
$filmTextList = @()
get-content -path $rootFolder\movielist.txt | %{$filmTextList += [PSCustomObject]@{Name=($_ -split "(\(\d{4}\))")[0];Year=($_ -split "(\(\d{4}\))")[1]}}

$filmFiles = get-childitem -path C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\test skript\test1
foreach ($film in $filmTextList){
    try{
    $matchedFilm = Get-Item ([WildcardPattern]::Escape($filmFiles.FullName -match $film.Name))
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $matchedFilm.FullName -NewName "$($film.Name) $($film.Year)$($matchedFilm.Extension)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }catch{}
}
```

Otherwise here's a working version of your 2nd attempt:

```
$rootFolder = "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\test skript\test1"
$files      = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -File
$filmTextList = @()
get-content -path $rootFolder\movielist.txt | %{$filmTextList += [PSCustomObject]@{Name=($_ -split "(\(\d{4}\))")[0];Year=($_ -split "(\(\d{4}\))")[1]}}
foreach ($film in $filmTextList) 
{
    $files | Where-Object {
        $_.BaseName -match $film.name
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $ext = $_.Extension
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "$($film.name)$($film.year)$ext" -EA 0
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some issues. For example if I have `Il cavaliere oscuro - il ritorno 1080p.mkv` and `Il cavaliere oscuro - il ritorno (2012).` file is renamed as `Il cavaliere oscuro (2008).mkv ` but this shouldn't happen because should be renamed as `Il cavaliere oscuro - Il ritorno (2012)`.mkv because in *movielist.txt* there is `Il cavaliere oscuro (2008)` and in folder I have a filename called `Il cavaliere oscuro.mkv` (is another film because year is different)

Comment: Other files that are not renamed are: `Halloween 2 - Il Signore Della Morte.avi`, `Highlander 2 1080p.mkv` and `Heartbreakers - Vizio di famiglia.avi`

Comment: You cannot easily do this accurately with the approach you're using.  Your movie files contain for example "Highlander" and "Highlander 2", so when we hit entry "Highlander" it will match against either. This wouldn't be a problem, except your movie files contain all sorts of random text not related to the movie title, e.g. "Hocus Pocus [DIVX - ITA] - Walt Disney - HQ-.avi". So in the case of "Highlander 2" and "Hocus Pocus", how am I meant to know that the "2" is part of the Highlander title but "Walt Disney" *isn't* part of the Hocus title?

Comment: You can know this because in the text file movielist.txt "Highlander" has a different year than Highlander 2. You can't know it from the filename, but the year of release is always present in the text file. For example Hightlander is from 1986 while Highlander 2 is from 1991, the files that I am going to rename never have the year in their name while in the text file it is always present